# writing into binary files

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class info {

private:
    char name[15];
    char surname[15];
    int age;
public:
    void input(){
        cout<<"Your name:"<<endl;
            cin.getline(name,15);
        cout<<"Your surname:"<<endl;
        cin.getline(surname,15);
        cout<<"Your age:"<<endl;
        cin>>age;
        to_file(name,surname,age);
    }

    void to_file(char name[15], char surname[15], int age){
        fstream File ("example.bin", ios::out  | ios::binary | ios::app);
    // I doesn't know how to fill all variables(name,surname,age) in 1 variable (memblock) 
        //example File.write ( memory_block, size ); 

File.close();
    }

};

int main(){

info ob;
ob.input();

 return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to write more than 1 variable into a file, please help, I included an example ;) Maybe there are better ways to write to a file, please help me with this, it's to hard for me to solve.

Comment: Off-topic to your question, but if you call `ob.input()` more than once, you'll discover a bug in your input code. Try adding `std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');` after `cin>>age`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For a *text* file, you could easily output one variable per line using a similar `<<` to the one you use with `std::cout`.

For a *binary* file, you need to use [`std::ostream::write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write), which writes a sequence of bytes. For your `age` attribute, you'll need to `reinterpret_cast` this to `const char*` and write as many bytes as is necessary to hold an `int` for your machine architecture. Note that if you intend to read this binary date on a different machine, you'll have to take [word size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) and [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) into consideration. I also recommend that you zero the `name` and `surname` buffers before you use them lest you end up with artefacts of uninitialised memory in your binary file.

Also, there's no need to pass attributes of the class into the `to_file()` method.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class info
{
private:
    char name[15];
    char surname[15];
    int age;

public:
    info()
        :name()
        ,surname()
        ,age(0)
    {
        memset(name, 0, sizeof name);
        memset(surname, 0, sizeof surname);
    }

    void input()
    {
        std::cout << "Your name:" << std::endl;
        std::cin.getline(name, 15);

        std::cout << "Your surname:" << std::endl;
        std::cin.getline(surname, 15);

        std::cout << "Your age:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> age;

        to_file();
    }

    void to_file()
    {
        std::ofstream fs("example.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
        fs.write(name, sizeof name);
        fs.write(surname, sizeof surname);
        fs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&age), sizeof age);
        fs.close();
    }
};

int main()
{
    info ob;
    ob.input();
}
```

A sample data file may look like this:

```
% xxd example.bin
0000000: 7573 6572 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0031  user...........1
0000010: 3036 3938 3734 0000 0000 0000 0000 2f00  069874......../.
0000020: 0000                                     ..
```

Comment: thanks! Perhaps it's a bit out of scope but what tools are there to inspect binary files?

Comment: @MinhTran: Yeah, that's a new question. Perhaps take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xxd/info ?

Answer (score 5):

```
File.write(name, 15);
File.write(surname, 15);
File.write((char *) &age, sizeof(age));
```

Comment: If I have more than 1 int variable for example `char name[15];
 char surname[15];
 int age, phone;`  when wite `File.write(name, 15);
File.write(surname, 15);
File.write((char *) &age&phone, sizeof(age&phone));`  ??

Comment: @user1069874: no, you can't connect them like that, you have to write them separately: `File.write(name, 15); File.write(surname, 15); File.write((char *) &age, sizeof(age)); File.write((char *) &phone, sizeof(phone));`

Comment: maybe is better `File.write ((char*)this, sizeof (info));` ?

Comment: @user1069874: you can do that, but then why do you pass all the variables as arguments to the function?

Comment: mhm I'm not know which methos is better, when use `File.write ((char*)this, sizeof (info));` then file use more space /:

Comment: @user1069874: its probably because of alignment.